# Webpack: I have different import types, can i have the names and links to the different types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm just starting with webpack on a project where I am in no way an JS ecosystem guru, and going into it I had the impression webpack would have me me working more consistently.  Maybe I should, but what i have is the following. (I am totally open to me doing it wrong). For instance `import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';` gives me a not a constructor error.  So I searched around and found the 'other way' and it worked fine.

So if someone could name the different types, why they're here, and links so I can have a reference that would be helpful.

```
require('../css/green.css');

import $ from 'jquery';

import { Slim } from 'slim-js';

var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like `import jsPDF from 'jspdf';` because its return object.